# Как сделать так, чтобы не было переноса в начало новой строки?

Tags: visual-studio

[image: screen]

Нужно сделать так, чтобы перенос закрывающей скобки был не в начало строки

Comment: Ctrl+k+d комбинация клавиш

Comment: когда нужно прожимать данную комбинацию клавиш?

Comment: Это автоформатирование. Вернет все убежавшие скобки на положенное место.

Comment: мне кажется, что топикстартер хочет чтобы по автоформату скобка не переносилась на отдельную строку

Comment: Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D - для всего файла Ctrl + K, Ctrl + F - для выделенного